# API key for Google maps on the project http://kislorod123.ru does not work

Tags: google-maps

API key for Google maps on the project http://kislorod123.ru does not work
At the same time we added the domain name in 3 versions: http://joxi.ru/BA0N8P7UMqal8m

[image: image of account settings]

At the moment, we have removed the restrictions for the maps to work on the sites, because we are a web studio and customers are complaining, but the map does not work either.
Tell me how to solve the problem with the operation of the API in the mode of limited access and without restrictions

Comment: What about `http://kislorod123.ru/*`?  Do maps work on `http://www.kislorod123.ru/`?

Comment: Yes. This record is present

Comment: I didn't see it in your picture (no `/*` at the end, which is different)

Comment: I added after your advice

Comment: Try removing the `&amp;` from your API include.

Comment: I did as you recommended, but the map still does not work.

Comment: restrictions http://prntscr.com/ncnkei

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the recommended format of http referrers. Remove all the restrictions for `kislorod123.ru` then add the following restrictions below:

```
kislorod123.ru
*.kislorod123.ru
```

These two will allow your API key to be used in all subdomains and paths in your website.

Also note to **remove any duplicate restrictions** as this will affect the restriction and may cause error. Also the `http://` is not necessary.

Comment: If the above solution doesn't work, I'd recommend that you please file a support case via https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support in order to open personalized communication channel as this may require more attention from Google.